# WP - Advanced Custom Fields : acf_add_options_page() does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to set up **Options Page** with **Advanced Custom Fields** in WP.

What I have in `functions.php` file :

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

acf_add_options_page();

acf_add_options_sub_page('General');
acf_add_options_sub_page('Header');
acf_add_options_sub_page('Footer');

}
```

The problem is that `function_exists('acf_add_options_page')` returns `false`.

Seems like that function does not exist, however I am using the latest version of ACF.

**When I try to use `acf_add_options_page();`:**

I get the following `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function acf_add_options_page()`

**When I avoid using `acf_add_options_page();`, using only `acf_add_options_sub_page()`:**

I get the following Warning(s)

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'slug' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\acf-options-page\acf-options-page.php on line 230

Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\acf-options-page\acf-options-page.php on line 230
```

**p.s.** I am using an **hook** (tried with *init*, **plugins_loaded** and *admin_init*) on `functions.php` to load the functions :

```
add_action('init', 'my_init_function');

    function my_init_function() {

    if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

        acf_add_options_page();

        acf_add_options_sub_page('General');
        acf_add_options_sub_page('Header');
        acf_add_options_sub_page('Footer');


    }

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your theme's function.php is loaded before the actual ACF extension? Is your functio_exists in a hook or directly in the function.php? If so, have you tried moving it in hook like so : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded

Comment: I am using a hook, tried init and admin_init, everything is possible I believe, thanks for the reference, just tried to use a hook with plugins_loaded and did not work.

Comment: Are you on a WP network?

Comment: No, I am building a theme for wp. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What version of ACF are you using?

Comment: ACF is 4.4.5 and ACF : Options Page is  1.2.0.

Comment: Solved by myself, I was just tired and was not being able to see the obvious. I just needed to select the 4th version at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-multiple-options-pages/?version=4

Comment: Because of this on available from:

This function requires at least ACF PRO version 5.0.0.

Comment: All ready display note on plugin please close the question.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/

Answer (score 15):

I was having a similar issue, however I was running the code as part of a must-use plugin.

The issue there is that acf plugins are loaded *after* mu-plugins, so the function did not exist yet.

I used the `plugins_loaded` action to run it right after all the plugins were loaded.

Here is my code:

```
// Add Options Page
function add_my_options_page() {
  if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    acf_add_options_page();
  }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'add_my_options_page' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try without add_action. Just do:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

acf_add_options_page(array(
    'page_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
    'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
    'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
    'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
    'redirect'      => true,
    'icon_url'      => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
    'position'      => 22
));

acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'page_title'    => 'General',
    'menu_title'    => 'General',
    'parent_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
));
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this `$parent['menu_slug']`

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    $parent = acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Theme General Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'General',
        'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'  => false,
    ));

    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Header',
        'menu_title'    => 'Header',
        'parent_slug'   => $parent['menu_slug'],
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'  => false,
    ));

    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Footer',
        'menu_title'    => 'Footer',
        'parent_slug'   => $parent['menu_slug'],
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'  => false,
    ));


}
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_sub_page/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i got it working:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
 acf_add_options_page(array(
  'page_title'  => 'Header Settings',
  'menu_title'  => 'Header',
  'menu_slug'   => 'header-settings'
 ));
acf_add_options_page(array(
  'page_title'  => 'General Settings',
  'menu_title'  => 'General',
  'menu_slug'   => 'general-settings'
 ));
acf_add_options_page(array(
  'page_title'  => 'Footer Settings',
  'menu_title'  => 'Footer',
  'menu_slug'   => 'footer-settings'
 ));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'     => 'Theme General Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Theme Options',
        'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'        => false,
        'icon_url' => 'dashicons-laptop',
    ));
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer